# Task.Factory.StartNew not executing the method in .net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, ftp, task-parallel-library

I have around 5000 files located in FTP, so i am downloading those by using FTP and then unzipping the files, finally processing and pushing in to oracle database.Except processing and pushing in to database everything going fine, i dont know why processing is not happeneing .I can see debugger hitting that method but it is not going in to inside method.How to fix this issue?

```
var list = ftp.GetFileList(remotepath);

 //-------------------
 DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
 string st = String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", dt);//20161120
 Task[] myTasks = new Task[list.Count];
 int i = 0;
 foreach (string item in list)
 {
    {
     if (item.StartsWith("GExport_") && (!item.ToUpper().Contains("DUM")) && (item.Contains(st)) && (!item.ToUpper().Contains("BLK")))
     {
        4gpath = item;
        //Downloadfile()   
        ftp.Get(dtr["REMOTE_FILE_PATH"].ToString() + 4gpath , @localDestnDir + "\\" + dtr["SOURCE_PATH"].ToString());
        download_location_hw = dtr["LOCAL_FILE_PATH"].ToString();
        // Spin off a background task to process the file we just downloaded
        myTasks[i++] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
           //Extractfile()             
           ExtractZipfiles(download_location_hw + "//" + huwawei4gpath, dtr["REMOTE_FILE_PATH"].ToString(), 
                 dtr["FTP_SERVER"].ToString(), dtr["FTP_USER_ID"].ToString(),
                 dtr["TECH_CODE"].ToString(), dtr["VENDOR_CODE"].ToString());
            //Extract the zip file referred to by  download_location_hw
            // Process the extracted zip file
            ProcessFile()
        });
      }
    }
  }
  Task.WaitAll(myTasks);
```

Here `ProcessFile()` method is not executing at all

**EDIT**
there was typo in `filepath` cause issue,thanks,but my question is is there any synchronization issue,since first unzip the file and same time process file where file was not available,will it wait for unzipping before processing –

added check `while(!File.Exists("")) { Thread.Sleep(1000);`
does that make any isssues??

Comment: How do you know that `ProcessFile` is not getting executed?  Did you try putting a breakpoint on that line?

Comment: i put break point there and can see that it is hitting there but not going inside and none of the datas are pushed in to database.where files are downloaded and extracted successfully

Comment: @peter probably you are debugging in the stack trace of the main thread.

Comment: Why do you have 2 braces after foreach?

Comment: @CodingYoshi by mistake i put,but does that make any issues??

Comment: FWIW, the FTP site may have a limit on the number of concurrent connections. Also try your code outside of a task, it will probably be easier to spot any issues.

Comment: @wdosanjos i did not get you,in order to fasten the process i used taks

Comment: @peter just for troubleshooting try executing your code outside of a task. The issue might not be related to the task itself, but to the code being executed in the task. It should be easier to debug this way.

Comment: @CodingYosh yeas you are correct,there was typo in filepath cause issue,thanks,but my question is is there any synchronization issue,since first unzip the file and same time process file where file was not available,will it wait for unzipping before processing

Comment: added check   while(!File.Exists(""))
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1000); 
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try this code here, you will notice it works. It is very similar to your code. Since this works, your issue is elsewhere and not related to Task(s).

```
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
     var list = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
     Task[] myTasks = new Task[ list.Count ];
     int i = 0;
     foreach( string item in list ) {

        // Spin off a background task to process the file we just downloaded
        myTasks[ i++ ] = Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
        {

           //Extract the zip file referred to by  download_location_hw
           // Process the extracted zip file
           ProcessFile();

           } );
     }



  Task.WaitAll( myTasks );

     Console.WriteLine( "in main after processing..." );
     Console.Read();
  }

  private static void ProcessFile() {
     Console.Write( "Processed..." );
  }
}
```

Comment: yeas you are correct,there was typo in filepath cause issue,thanks,but my question is is there any synchronization issue,since first unzip the file and same time process file where file was not available,will it wait for unzipping before processing.Because now i am geting file couldnot available like

Comment: i added this check   while(!File.Exists(""))
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1000); 
  } does that make any issues

Comment: Can you please edit the question as quite a few people have voted asking you to do this. I can then help you.

Comment: @peter Please also include the plumbing of the Process method in your edited question so I can see if you are using tasks there.